# I can't seem to find this derivative any help would be great.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, physics

A rocket of mass m = 1000 kg is traveling in a straight line for a short time. The distance in meters covered by the rocket during this time is described by the function

$r(t)=t^3 −3t^2 +6t$

where $t > 0$ is the time in seconds.

The kinetic energy E of the rocket is given by $E = mv^2/2$ and $v=2$
is the rocket’s speed. Find a function that describes the kinetic energy of the rocket.

I thought you might use the second derivative? But have no idea what is the function im looking for?

Comment: The derivative of the position (here, distance covered) is the speed.

Comment: I thought the kinetic energy was $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$?

Comment: It is, and OP reflects it properly now.

Comment: the question i have has kinetic energy at e= mv^2/2 not 1/2mv^2

Answer (score 2):

First note that
$$v(t)=\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(t^3-3t^2+6t)=3t^2-6t+6$$
Then the kinetic energy $E$ is
$E=\frac 12 mv^2=500(3t^2-6t+6)^2$

Comment: But the velocity should be squared...(and we are also supposing that the OP lives in a universe with doubled kinetic energy :) )

Comment: I think the kinetic energy is $mv^2/2$!

Comment: @RobertLewis That's what I said as well (if you read my comment to OP's question)

Comment: Yeah, it bears repeating!